# 1x1x1 Rubiks Cube Puzzle

Tags: rubiks-cube, retrograde-analysis, twisty-puzzles

[image]

The solved position of 1x1x1 Rubiks cubes as shown  was  shuffle rolled  without moving outside the 4x4 puzzle grid. All cubes are similar with face opposite colors: red to magenta,green to yellow and blue to cyan. Within its grid the puzzle can be played  by quarter rolling the cubes up,down,left or right. If the shuffled position as shown has all cubes at the corners of the puzzle grid, how to solve it back to original position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

> 16 moves are required.

Like so:

> [image]

Since the cubes are all similar, it's sufficient to check that 2 of the colours end up correctly oriented, the order of the other colours is then forced.

To avoid collisions, the top left cube can be moved first (all but the last square), then the top right and bottom right cubes can go to their spots, followed by the top left cube's final move, and finally the bottom left cube has an open route.

Unless I missed something, each path in the picture is the shortest route for that cube to end up correctly oriented in *any* of the centre squares. That makes this the shortest possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

> The bottom-right cuve can be rolled UULL and be correctly orientated in the top-left. The bottom-left cube can similarly be moved to the bottom-right.
>
>  The top-left can be moved D to be orientated correctly but diagonally one step away from the bottom left. Similarly, the top-right can be moved LL to end up diagonally one step away from the top right and correctly orientated.
>
>  Now, RDL moves a cube one orthogonal square and rotates it 90°. Two moves like this can translate a piece as needed.
>
>  After that it's just sequencing to avoid collisions. So I suspect it's possible.